# How can I determine the path to the C# compiler?

Tags: c#, frameworks, sdk

Is the path for the C# compiler, csc.exe, stored in a reference location somewhere?

I am working on a custom tool to compile code snippets into their own DLL's by the users so location could vary, would like to automate this as much as possible before resorting to the locate file dialog box!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Is there any reason you want to invoke the binary directly, instead of using [`CSharpCodeProvider`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.csharp.csharpcodeprovider.aspx) to programmatically compile?

You may be interested in my own snippet compiler (Snippy), which you can download the source for [on my C# in Depth site](http://csharpindepth.com/Downloads.aspx).

Comment: +1 for the programmatic view. No -1 for self-promotion, because Snippy's actually useful.

Comment: interesting, will look into this
Does this *require* a code file ? in this case there's only a custom function to compile from the code editor

Comment: No - I never write the source to disk in Snippy, for example.

Answer (score 6):

You can find the compiler here:

```
%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v[version number]\csc.exe
```

So, for .net 3.5, it would be

```
%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v3.5\csc.exe
```

Answer (score 1):

Look at the document [Command-line Building With csc.exe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/78f4aasd.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Not that I'm aware of.  You can add it to your Environment Variable (Control Panel > System > Advanced > Environment Variables and add it under PATH).  The path would be C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework[Framework Version] -- for example: C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727.